# Dynamic scatter plot in Ploty - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, ggplotly

I'm trying to create a scatter plot with Ploty that allow me to display the different species of the Iris dataset plus a square for each species representing the min and max values for Sepal length and width.
To clarify, I want something like this for each species:
[image]

For that, I've created a list of scatter plots + squares for each species, and I want to call each item on the list (a chart + a square for the specie selected) with the dropdown menu. So far I've failed to do that.
I've also tried to do the "standard" procedure of plotting the species in a scatter ggplot, create it to a ploty chart and add the dropdown menu. That workerd fine for interactively select each specie, but I can't managed to change the limits of the square when a new species is selected.

This is my code so far (the one that stores the ggplots + the squares in a list):

```
data("iris")
flw <-data.frame(iris)
flw_squares <- data.frame(spc = c("setosa","virginica","versicolor"),
                            sep_lg_min = c(4.5,6.5,5),
                            sep_lg_max = c(5.8,8,7),
                            sep_wd_min = c(3.2,2.5,2.5),
                            sep_wd_max = c(4.25,3.5,3.5))

flw_lst <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(flw_squares$spc)){
  spc_selected= flw_squares$spc[i]
  flw_lst[i,1] <- flw_squares$spc[i]
  flw_lst[i,2] <- as.numeric((flw%>%filter(Species== spc_selected)%>%
                                filter(Sepal.Length==min(as.numeric(Sepal.Length),na.rm = TRUE)))$Sepal.Length)[1]
  flw_lst[i,3] <- as.numeric((flw%>%filter(Species== spc_selected)%>%
                                filter(Sepal.Length==max(as.numeric(Sepal.Length),na.rm = TRUE)))$Sepal.Length)[1]
  flw_lst[i,4] <- as.numeric((flw%>%filter(Species== spc_selected)%>%
                                filter(Sepal.Width==min(as.numeric(Sepal.Width),na.rm = TRUE)))$Sepal.Width)[1]
  flw_lst[i,5] <- as.numeric((flw%>%filter(Species== spc_selected)%>%
                                filter(Sepal.Width==max(as.numeric(Sepal.Width),na.rm = TRUE)))$Sepal.Width)[1]
  }

colnames(flw_lst)<-c("Species","min Sepal.Length","max Sepal.Length","min Sepal.Width","max Sepal.Width")

# ggplot(flw,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+
#          geom_point(aes(color=Species))

spc_lst<-list()

for (i in 1:length(flw_squares$spc)){
  
  spc_selected=flw_lst[i,1]
  #INTERACTIVE SCATTER PLOT
  spc_p<-flw%>%filter(Species== spc_selected) %>%ggplot(aes(y=Sepal.Width ,x=Sepal.Length ))+
    theme_bw()+ ggtitle(paste("Scatter plot "),spc_selected) +
    geom_point(shape=21, size=3, stroke=.2)+
    scale_color_manual(values = "black")+
    scale_fill_manual(name="Species")+
    labs(color = "Species") +  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "horizontal")+
    geom_rect(aes(  

      xmin= as.numeric((flw%>%filter(Species== spc_selected)%>%
                                    filter(Sepal.Length==min(as.numeric(Sepal.Length),na.rm = TRUE)))$Sepal.Length)[1],
      xmax= as.numeric((flw%>%filter(Species== spc_selected)%>%
                                    filter(Sepal.Length==max(as.numeric(Sepal.Length),na.rm = TRUE)))$Sepal.Length)[1],
      ymin= as.numeric((flw%>%filter(Species== spc_selected)%>%
                                    filter(Sepal.Width==min(as.numeric(Sepal.Width),na.rm = TRUE)))$Sepal.Width)[1],
      ymax= as.numeric((flw%>%filter(Species== spc_selected)%>%
                                    filter(Sepal.Width==max(as.numeric(Sepal.Width),na.rm = TRUE)))$Sepal.Width)[1],
      ),
      fill = "transparent",color = "red", size = .4)
  
  spc_p=ggplotly(spc_p)
  
  spc_lst[[i]]<- plotly_build(spc_p)
  
}

spc_lst[[1]] %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(title = "y"),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y = 0.7,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
               label = "setosa"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
               label = "virginica"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
               label = "versicolor")))
    )
  )
```

Do you have any ideas on how to tackle this issue? I think that it's better to create a ggplot, add the dropdowm menu with ploty and then select the species from the chart, but I can´t manage to "listen" to the event and change the limits on the `geom_rect` part of the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this approach might work.

For rectangles, define your shapes in a list for each of the three groups you are interested in (in this case, `Species`).

Then, your `plotly` plot will have your three traces, one for each group. The first could have a default of `visible = TRUE`.

In your `updatemenus` `buttons` list, you can set everything, including visibility and the rectangle shapes.

```
library(plotly)

df <- iris

species_names <- unique(df$Species)

shapes <- lapply(species_names, function(x) {
  list(
    type = "rect",
    x0 = min(df[df$Species == x, "Sepal.Length"]), 
    x1 = max(df[df$Species == x, "Sepal.Length"]), 
    xref = "x",
    y0 = min(df[df$Species == x, "Sepal.Width"]),
    y1 = max(df[df$Species == x, "Sepal.Width"]), 
    yref = "y",
    line = list(color = "red"),
    layer = "below",
    opacity = .5
  )
}) 

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = df[df$Species == species_names[1],], 
            x = ~Sepal.Length, 
            y = ~Sepal.Width, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'markers', 
            visible = T) %>%
  add_trace(data = df[df$Species == species_names[2],], 
            x = ~Sepal.Length, 
            y = ~Sepal.Width, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'markers', 
            visible = F) %>%
  add_trace(data = df[df$Species == species_names[3],], 
            x = ~Sepal.Length, 
            y = ~Sepal.Width, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'markers', 
            visible = F) %>%
  layout(
    shapes = list(shapes[[1]]),
    updatemenus = list(
    list(y = .7,     
         buttons = list(
           list(method = "update",
                args = list(list(visible = c(T, F, F)),
                            list(title = species_names[1], 
                                 shapes = list(shapes[[1]]))),
                label = species_names[1]),
           list(method = "update",
                args = list(list(visible = c(F, T, F)),
                            list(title = species_names[2], 
                                 shapes = list(shapes[[2]]))),
                label = species_names[2]),
           list(method = "update",
                args = list(list(visible = c(F, F, T)),
                            list(title = species_names[3], 
                                 shapes = list(shapes[[3]]))),
                label = species_names[3])
         )))
  )
```

**Plot**

[image: plotly plot with dropdown and rectangles]

Comment: It worked perfect, @Ben , thank you very much.  Really difficult nesting of list in the updatemenus section, I'd never figure it out by myself. Tha nks again!